# How to login to instagram using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram-api

Need to login to instagram with `login and password`, and then get a token.

At what address to send a request?

Comment: Check their [api docs](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Comment: I assume you registerd on www.instagram.com/developer. You can get an access token for your account via: https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token

But I think you want your app users to login through instagram, so you can retrieve their access_token to make requests through the instagram API.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you already registered on www.instagram.com/developer, and got an access token for your account via:
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token
. If this is the case, you probably want your app users to login through instagram, so you can retrieve their access_token to make requests through the instagram API.

For this I suggest adding the following gems to your gem file

```
gem 'omniauth-instagram'
gem 'instagram'
```

Next, you need to create an initializer for OAuth, if you're using devise for authentication, go to config/initializers and edit the devise.rb. Add the following line to the code

```
config.omniauth :instagram, ENV["INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET"]
```

Remember to tell devise about omniauthable in your user model

```
devise :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
```

If you're using devise for authentication, there are a bunch of railscast videos, that do justice to the topic, I suggest you go through those.

For the remaining steps using the API via the instagram gem see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362907

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the official [Instagram Ruby gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem).

First step is to register yourself [here](https://instagram.com/developer/) and get the authentication token.

Once you have installed the gem using:

```
gem install instagram
```

and got your authentication token. Initialize `Instagram` in `config/initializers`

```
require "instagram"
Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "client_id goes here"
  config.access_token = "access_token goes here"
end
```

Following this you can access user media as follows:

```
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("user_id_here", {:count => 1})
```

This is just one simple example. Refer [docs](https://instagram.com/developer) for details.