# Fetching all user's pictures with the Instagram gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram, instagram-api

I'd like to fetch all my pictures using the instagram gem (https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) but I'm not able to find out how.

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
client = Instagram.client(access_token: token)
client.user_recent_media.each do |media|
    puts media.images.thumbnail.url
end
```

It apparently works (those are my Instagram images) but I'm not able to fetch **all of them** or to select in any way which content I want from Instagram.

For example I see that the method user_recent_media accepts a *"count"* attribute that should let me use some sort of pagination:

```
(from https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/blob/master/lib/instagram/client/users.rb#L150)
@option options [Integer] :count (nil) Limits the number of results returned per page
```

Unfortunately I don't get how this paginations is supposed to work. If for example I request 1000 media elements (just to say all of them) it doesn't work and returns way less elements, at that point I'm stuck because I have no idea how to requeste page 2

Has anyone used the Instagram gem for something like this? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is functioning code from an old app that imports users (I just ran it with the 1.1.5 Instagram Gem and it still works), which also uses the cursor. You should be able to change a few variables and lines and be on your way:

```
  def import_followers
    response = user.client.user_follows
    followers = [].concat(response)
    next_cursor = response.pagination[:next_cursor]
    while !(next_cursor.to_s.empty?) do
      response = Instagram.user_follows(uid, {:cursor => next_cursor})
      next_cursor = response.pagination[:next_cursor]
      followers.concat(response)
    end
    return followers
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer of @nrowegt, I customised the code.

First, we initialize the Instagram Gem (the access token will map the Instagram user ID)

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
```

Then, we will run the user_recent_media method and save the response in a variable

```
response = client.user_recent_media
```

We need to create an empty array to save all the pictures and add our response. Remember, Instagram API only returns 20 items per call, that's why we need to do the array and the "while" below.

```
album = [].concat(response)
```

If the user has more picture, the response variable will have a variable called next_max_id. This is inside of pagination method; so we store the next_max_id on a variable.

```
max_id = response.pagination.next_max_id
```

This is the tricky part. You need to run the above's code while the max_id variable exists. It will be empty if we reach the last page of the user's pictures. So:

```
while !(max_id.to_s.empty?) do
        response = client.user_recent_media(:max_id => max_id)
        max_id = response.pagination.next_max_id
        album.concat(response)
end
```

With the ONLY differente that this time we run the user_recent_media method passing the max_id variable so Instagram can figure out where to start fetching the pictures.

And we send the final variable to the view

```
@album = album
```

Here is the full code.

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
        response = client.user_recent_media
        album = [].concat(response)
        max_id = response.pagination.next_max_id

        while !(max_id.to_s.empty?) do
            response = client.user_recent_media(:max_id => max_id)
            max_id = response.pagination.next_max_id
            album.concat(response)
        end

        @album = album
```

Comment: May Zeus and Odin bless you with eternal life

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) you should receive a `pagination` hash in any response you'll receive from the API. Something like the following (taken from the documentation):

```
{
    ...
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/puppy/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&max_id=13872296",
        "next_max_id": "13872296"
    }
}
```

You'll have to call the URL from the `next_url` attribute to retrieve the next set of data.

So, I'm guessing that you should be able to retrieve that as follows:

```
client.user_recent_media.pagination.next_url
```